# How to keep moved (Added) image in the same div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, image

Hi all iam working on jquery here i have a html page. in the html i have two div's in those `firstdiv` contains
 `image, name, and price` right now we have to move(add) image to another div which is empty div here i had done to (move) add
 image form first to secound `but problem is` when image added to the secound  div the images should be appear in the 
 same place   in first div and also in the secound div i had done to image add to secound div but images removes from the first div
 this is my code follows:

```
               <div>              
                <span class="span1">
                <img src="~/Images/galaxy.jpeg" /></span> 
            <span class="span1">1232</span>
            <span class="span2">Cell Phone</span> 
            <span class="span1">3500</span>              
           <a href="#" class="pull-right" ><i class="icon-plus" onclick="AddToCart(this)" id="btnid" ></i></a>
        </div>


           <div class="span7" style="border:1px black" id="separat">
            </div>
```

in the above code iam having 'icon-plus'  button when i click the button it adding image to the secound div but  i need
 images should add and it shoul appear in the same place also

and this is my jquery

```
              $(function () {             
       AddToCart(this);                
  });
    function AddToCart(obj) {
        var val = 0;
      var $this = $(obj).closest('div');
      var img = $this.find('img');
      var image=img;
      $('#separat').append(img);
      }
```

Could anybody please help me to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you sholud use `clone()`

```
function AddToCart(obj) {
        var val = 0;
      var $this = $(obj).closest('div');
      var img = $this.find('img').clone();
      var image=img;
      $('#separat').append(img);
      }
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes. When used in conjunction
>   with one of the insertion methods, **.clone() is a convenient way to
>   duplicate elements on a page.**

**UPDATE**

if you want to get the prize and name

```
prize = $(obj).closest('.span2').clone();
name = $(obj).closest('.span1').clone();

$('#separat').append(img+prize+name);
```

Comment: thanks u very much @kanishka panamadeniya thanks very much nice codin friend thanks for my reply her i need to move name and price also how could i do that

Comment: try $('#separat').append(img,prize,name);

Comment: when i keep the alert i am getting [object Object] and even printing [object Object]

Comment: for price and for name i am getting [object Object][object Object] only

Answer (score 1):

try change

```
$('#separat').append(img);
```

to

```
$(img).clone().appendTo("#separat");
```

Comment: thanks for my reply it's working one more help plz i need to move image as well as name and price alse how could i do that to the secound div